# How to find the real or imaginary part of an equation involving complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am currently using the Debye model and need to find the real and imaginary parts of the equation. The Debye equation is

$$ \epsilon_\text{r} = \epsilon_\infty + \frac{\epsilon_\text{s} - \epsilon_\infty}{1+i\frac{\omega\epsilon}{\sigma}} - i\frac{\sigma}{\omega\epsilon_0}, $$

where $i^2 = -1$.

How would I find $\mathfrak{R}\{\epsilon_\text{r}\}$ and $\mathfrak{I}\{\epsilon_\text{r}\}$ from this equation?

Comment: Are any of the other quantities complex numbers? If not use conjugate multiplication on the first fraction...

Comment: What is real and what is complex in your equation?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not actually sure which quantities are real or imaginary. I think—as Autolatry assumed—everything is real apart from $i$, since this relation originates from engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all symbols are real except for the complex unit. Then the second term is fine; consider the first:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\epsilon_{s}-\epsilon_{\infty}}{1+i\frac{\omega \epsilon}{\sigma}} &=& \frac{\epsilon_{s}-\epsilon_{\infty}}{1+i\frac{\omega \epsilon}{\sigma}}\frac{i}{i}\\
&=& \frac{i(\epsilon_{s}-\epsilon_{\infty})}{i-\frac{\omega \epsilon}{\sigma}}
\end{eqnarray}
Now multiply both numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{(-i-\frac{\omega \epsilon}{\sigma})}{(-i-\frac{\omega \epsilon}{\sigma})}\frac{i(\epsilon_{s}-\epsilon_{\infty})}{i-\frac{\omega \epsilon}{\sigma}}
&=& \frac{i(\epsilon_{s}-\epsilon_{\infty})(-i-\frac{\omega \epsilon}{\sigma})}{1+\frac{\omega^{2}}{\epsilon^{2}\sigma^{2}}}\\
\end{eqnarray}
Now multiply out the brackets on the numerator and include the second term I omitted above and then collect real and imaginary parts.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did not realise it would be so simple!

Comment: You're welcome! Cheers.

Comment: @Autolatry similarly, could you help me with [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738887/how-to-find-the-real-part-of-a-complex-number-that-is-complicated)?
I am new to math.stackexchange, and I don't know if posting my question on someone else's is permitted or not, but I really want this question answered please

Answer (score 1):

Outcome with Autolatry's help:

$$ \epsilon_r = \epsilon_\infty + \frac{ \epsilon_\text{s} + \left(\frac{\omega\epsilon}{\sigma}-1 \right)  \epsilon_\infty }{1+\frac{\omega^2\epsilon^2}{\sigma^2}} - i\left[\frac{\omega\epsilon\sigma}{\sigma^2+\omega^2\epsilon^2} + \frac{\sigma}{\omega\epsilon_0}\right],$$

and so

$$ \mathfrak{R}(\epsilon_r) = \epsilon_\infty + \frac{ \epsilon_\text{s} + \left(\frac{\omega\epsilon}{\sigma}-1 \right)  \epsilon_\infty }{1+\frac{\omega^2\epsilon^2}{\sigma^2}} $$

$$ \mathfrak{I}(\epsilon_r) = -\frac{\omega\epsilon\sigma}{\sigma^2+\omega^2\epsilon^2} - \frac{\sigma}{\omega\epsilon_0}. $$

I'm sure these could be simplified a little further but they suffice for now.